# Add mysql library to ROS package

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like connect ros node with a Mysql DB but I can't do it. I don't know how use mysql lib client in Ros node because when compiled it appears error as undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info'. I'm try use cpp cflags export in package.xml but I can't found the correct way to do it.

Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203189/add-mysql-library-to-ros-package/) by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is a `catkin` package, treat the `CMakeLists.txt` as you would any ordinary CMake package.

Use `find_package(..)` and friends to look for the MySQL headers, libraries and other files. Then add those to your include path (`include_directories(..)`). Make sure to link your node executable to the libraries (`target_link_libraries(target_name ${mysql_LIBRARIES})`). Make sure to check the names of those Find script variables for yourself, as I did not check them.

> I'm try use cpp cflags export in package.xml but I can't found the correct way to do it.

cpp flags is something from `rosbuild`, which isn't used/supported anymore under `catkin`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0